# How to pass only one argument to odeint?

Tags: python, scipy, tuples, odeint

I am trying to use scipy's `odeint` to solve some ordinary differential equations.  The only problem is that I only want to define one argument, and it seems that to make a tuple, you need at least two values.

My code looks like this:

```
def system(state, t, inputs)

    x = state[0]
    u = inputs
    a = -4
    b = 2

    dxdt = [a * x + b * u]

    return dxdt

inputs = 5
x_next = odeint(system, x, t, args=(inputs))
```

This will return an error because `args` must be a tuple, and (inputs) is a int/float and not a tuple.  One way to overcome this is to put a, b as part of the args.  But that is just a bandaid on a wound.

I was wondering if there is any ways to define the args as just one value.

Comment: Use `args=(inputs,)`. Note the additional comma.

Comment: that was a lot easier than in my wildest dreams.  Thanks Cleb!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error says `args` has to be a `tuple`. You can turn the current version easily into a tuple by using

```
args=(inputs,)
```

Note the additional comma.